# Problem with mysql date query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
mysql> desc persondb;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name   | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lname  | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mydate | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from persondb;
+------------+--------+---------------------+
| name       | lname  | mydate              |
+------------+--------+---------------------+
| vishwanath | dalvi  | 2011-08-21 14:50:37 |
| ishwar     | dalvi  | 2011-08-21 14:50:58 |
| ganesh     | kamble | 2011-08-31 14:50:37 |
+------------+--------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select name,mydate from persondb
    -> where date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 5 DAY)<=mydate;
+------------+---------------------+
| name       | mydate              |
+------------+---------------------+
| vishwanath | 2011-08-21 14:50:37 |
| ishwar     | 2011-08-21 14:50:58 |
| ganesh     | 2011-08-31 14:50:37 |
+------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm using the following query to retrieve the records that matched interval of last 5 days but it is showing the entry of future date which is  `ganesh  | 2011-08-31 14:50:37`

```
  mysql> select name,mydate from persondb
      -> where date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 5 DAY)<=mydate;
```

Can anybody tell me the reason behind this ?

Comment: keyword `INTERVAL` doesnt mean range in query but amount of time (to do the calculus with)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT name,mydate FROM persondb
WHERE mydate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND NOW();
```

The reason your query shows dates in the future is because you check if mydate is later or equal to 5 days ago. The date `2011-08-31 14:50:37` fullfils this requirement. You can use `BETWEEN` to check if it is in the range between now and 5 days ago.

Comment: for original question author: `between` is more readable form and equal to `mydate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND mydate <= NOW()`

Comment: @Viswanathan in your question's query, yes.

Comment: `where mydate BETWEEN now() and date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 5 DAY);` if if put now() first then it returns empty why so ?

Comment: Because "BETWEEN ... AND ..." is defined to have the MIN value first and the MAX value second. `expr BETWEEN min AND max` Have a look at the [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)